# jolt transformation : remove duplicates from json (list elements)

Tags: jolt

I am looking for some inputs to remove duplicates from a json string similar to below sample :

Sample Input :

```json
{
  "profile": true,
  "address": [
    "12",
    "23"
  ],
  "zipCodes": [
    "12345",
    "56789",
    "12345",
    "56789"
  ],
  "phoneNumber": [
    "87857",
    "927465",
    "274894",
    "87857"
  ],
  "userName": [
    "ABC",
    "PQR",
    "ABC"
  ],
  "enableEmailNot": "No"
}
```

Expected Output :

```json
{
  "profile": true,
  "zipCodes": [
    "12345",
    "56789"
  ],
  "phoneNumber": [
    "87857",
    "927465",
    "274894"
  ],
  "userName": [
    "ABC",
    "PQR"
  ],
  "address": [
    "12",
    "23"
  ],
  "enableEmailNot": "No"
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following specs

```json
[
  {
   // exchange key-value pairs while seperating lists and non-lists by prefixing "xx" non-lists

    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "profile": "xx.&",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.@(0)"
        }
      },
      "enableEmailNot": "xx.&"
    }
  },
  {
   // pick the first components of lists  
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // reform the lists through use of "$" operator   
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "xx": {
        "*": "&"
      },
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: you're welcome @Harsha , good luck!

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, adding to previous question , one thing if there are 2 elements in the list for an attribute (both same value) , the above spec is removing the dups as expected but it's not a list but getting converted to as string

Comment: For the below input :
{
  "profile": true,
   "enableEmailNot": "No",
  "address": [
    "12",
    "12"
  ],
  "zipCodes": [
    "12345",
    "56789",
    "12345",
    "56789"
  ] 
}

Expected output is : 
{
  "profile" : true,
  "enableEmailNot" : "No",
  "address" : ["12"],
  "zipCodes" : [ "12345", "56789" ]
}

Result with above spec :
{
  "profile" : true,
  "enableEmailNot" : "No",
  "address" : "12",
  "zipCodes" : [ "12345", "56789" ]
}

Comment: Hi @Harsha , you can just replace last `&2` with `&2[]`